# Product Recommendation - Pocket accordion magnet bencher

Tags: product-recommendation

I was hoping you guys here could help me locate an item I've been looking for. A bit over a decade ago, I picked up one of those pocket-sized Bencher/Mincha/Maariv things that was in the form of an accordion magnet. Coincidentally, my wife around that time also happened to find one of those as well, completely independent of how I found one. Moving forward to today, that bencher has seen quite a bit of wear and is falling apart.

Does anyone know where I could find a replacement for that style of pocket bencher? I've stepped into several Judaica stores and tried my hand at Google, but haven't been able to find it anywhere.

For reference, see below picture of the style I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: Glue some magnets to the outside of a regular soft cover paper one

Comment: @DoubleAA If I can't find a prefabricated one, I do plan on making one by hand. Gluing magnets onto a regular book won't work, as the pages would be in "book" shape. What I'm looking for is where the paper opens up in one long strip, and folded closed with the magnets.

Comment: Where'd you get the original one?

Comment: @ezra Both my wife and I independently got these from different Simchas (mine was from the Bar Mitzvah of a classmate).

Comment: @Salmononius2 If it was "from the Bar Mitzvah of a classmate" it must have been a long time ago, since you mentioned you're married now.

Comment: @ezra Yup, that's why I was hoping someone could point me to where I'd be able to get a new one, as I haven't been able to source one in person.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if this is what you are looking for but have a look at this

https://www.gr8gifts4u.com/birkathamazon-magnetic.html

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  The OP is asking about folding ones that fit in a pocket; that looks like a larger fridge magnet.